# Trouble linking accounts with Claim ID

Tags: support, openid, hyperlinks

I use Claim ID in SE sites. However for some sites I register as openid.claimid.com/louisr, and for some others claimid.com/louisr. Both of these are actually the same Claim ID account, it's just that I typed it differently at the first time. How do I let the system know that they are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [your user page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151823/louis-rhys) there's a link labeled "add openid" that will let you add a second openid to your account. Go through your existing SE accounts and add the variant that isn't already attached to your account to each. Once they all have the same two openids, you can use the [accounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1474?tab=accounts#tab-top) tab to associate all the accounts